# Correlation test issues

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics

**No error in 10.0.2**

---

When using `Correlation[]` function I sometimes get the strange warning:

```
CorrelationTest::nortst: "At least one of the p-values in {0.0527317}, resulting from a test for normality, is below 0.05`. The tests in \!\({\"PearsonCorrelation\"}\) require that the data is normally distributed."
```

But take a look that there's only one p-value and it is actually greater than $0.05$:

```
0.0527317 < 0.05
False
```

The code that causes this:

```
x = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 100];
y = 2 x + 1 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, 100];
X = Transpose[{x, y}];
ListPlot[X]
Correlation[X] // MatrixForm
CorrelationTest[X, 99995/100000, "PearsonCorrelation"]
```

Why this happens? 
(to reproduce the issue a few repetitions are usually required)

Comment: The end of the warning states: "The tests in {PearsonCorrelation} require that the data is normally distributed." You are drawing from a uniform distribution so your data is not sufficiently "normal" looking for the test.

Comment: @BobHanlon yes, but it is stated on the basis of the PValue. And PValue is greater than the $\alpha=0.05$ so it shouldn't write that warning in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in the reporting mechanism. The individual components `x` and `y` are being tested for normality but the reported value is that of a joint test for multivariate normality.  The conclusion is correct, the message is wrong.

```
SeedRandom[2154];

x = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 100];
y = 2 x + 1 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, 100];
X = Transpose[{x, y}];
CorrelationTest[X, 99995/100000, "PearsonCorrelation"]

(* CorrelationTest::nortst: At least one of the p-values 
in {0.0492268}, resulting from a test for normality, is below 0.05`. The tests in
{PearsonCorrelation} require that the data is normally distributed. >>

0.540402 *)
```

Marginal tests:

```
DistributionFitTest[x]

(* 0.00121523 *)

DistributionFitTest[y]

(* 0.00123259 *)
```

Joint test for multivariate normality. Notice the p-value matches the one in the message:

```
DistributionFitTest[X]

(* 0.0492268 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

No error nv 10.0.2. On windows 7, 64 bit

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SeedRandom[0];
x = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 100];
y = 2 x + 1 + RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, 100];
X = Transpose[{x, y}];
ListPlot[X]
Correlation[X] // MatrixForm
CorrelationTest[X, 99995/100000, "PearsonCorrelation"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

No error messages.